# pass addtional parameter to callback

Tags: go

I am using the phao mqtt module to communicate with a mqtt server.

Now I want to subscribe to a topic, for this I need to [pass](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang/blob/v1.3.0/client.go#L58) a callback with type [`MessageHandler`](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang/blob/v1.3.0/options.go#L36). Is it somehow possible to pass an additional parameter to the `MessageHandler`?

My handler looks like this so far:

```
var MyMessageHandler mqtt.MessageHandler = func(client mqtt.Client, msg mqtt.Message) {
    fmt.Printf("Received message: %s from topic: %s\n", msg.Payload(), msg.Topic())
    # Call here a stuct method
}
```

Comment: you can use closures to use or call something in your message handler when it is defined like that. https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/25

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- define a function that returns `mqtt.MessageHandler` and accepts your struct
- define a method on your struct and the same signature of `mqtt.MessageHandler`

```golang
type S struct{}

func MessageHandler(s S) mqtt.MessageHandler {
  return func(client mqtt.Client, msg mqtt.Message) {
    // use `s`
    // ...
  }
}

func (s *S) MessageHandler(client mqtt.Client, msg mqtt.Message) {
  // use `s`
  // ...
}
```

Usage:

```golang
func main() {
  s := S{}
  mh := MessageHandler(s)

  mh = s.MessageHandler // same type
  // use mh
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the handler from a func, creating a closure around the struct object who's method you need to call.

Here is a way to do that. Note that I have not used the lib so below main func might not compile, but you will get the idea:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)


type SomeStruct struct{}

func (ss *SomeStruct) Invoke() {
    fmt.Println("struct method called")
}

func GetHandler(s *SomeStruct) mqtt.MessageHandler {

    return func(client mqtt.Client, msg mqtt.Message) {
        fmt.Printf("Received message: %s from topic: %s\n", msg.Payload(), msg.Topic())
        s.Invoke()
    }
}

func main() {
    handler := GetHandler(&SomeStruct{})

    //pass to lib or assume it is invoked by lib
    //handler(Client{}, Message{})
}
```